# Como puedo agregar dos botones de siguiente y atras a una galeria en materialize CSS

Tags: materialize

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo, utilizado el framework Materialize CSS alguien sabe como podria crear dos botones uno de atras y uno de adelante, ya vi toda su docs y la verdad no lo encuentro y igualmente busque en internet y no encuentro nada relacionado a este framework.

Mi codigo actual de mi galeria:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Lovi acabados</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 
  
.nav-wrapper{
  background:#ff7334;
}

.nav-content{
  background:#0D0D0D;
}

.page-footer{
  height:505px;
    background:#000000;

}

.contactoinfo{
  color:#F2F2F2;
}
.tarjetas{
  color:#fff;
}

/*MENU*/


</style>
<body>

  <nav style="background:#ff7334;"  class=" lighten-1" role="navigation">
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Lovi Acabados</a></li>
<li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>      </ul>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
<li><a  href="producto2.html">Azulejo</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto3.html">Barro</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto4.html">Block</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto5.html">Cantera</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto6.html">Esculturas reducidas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto7.html">Fuentes</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto8.html">Granito</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto9.html">Iluminación</a></li>
        <li><a href="producto10.html">Jacuzzi</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto11.html">Ladrillo refractario</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto12.html">Mármol</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto13.html">Piedras decorativas</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto15.html">Piso</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto17.html">Sanitarios</a></li>
        <li><a  href="producto16.html">Tejas</a></li>      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
<!-- Galeria principal -->
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">

 <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img id="active" src="img/logo.png"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Lovi Acabados</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/2.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Las mejores piedras de sonora</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Necesitas decorar tu casa, somos los expertos.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/3.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption right-align">
          <h3>Virgenes de Guadalupe</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Tenemos las mejores estatuas de la virgen de Guadalupe hechas a mano por nuestros expertos.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/5.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Amas a los animales !</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Tenemos las mejores esculturas de animales decorativos para tu Hogar.</h5>
        </div>
              <li>
        <img src="img/6.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Nos has decorado tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Decora tu casa con las mejores piedras de sonora.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/7.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale un toque unico a tu casa</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Lovi Acabados tenemos las mejores decoracion del estado.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/8.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale Paz y alegria a tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">En Lovi Acabados tenemos para ti las virgenes de guadalupe talladas a mano.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/9.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale elegancia a tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Dale elegancia a tu casa con las mejores esculturas de piedra para tu casa.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <img src="img/10.JPG"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>Dale  distincion a tu casa!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Dale distincion a tu hogar con las mejores estaturas de piedra para ti aqui en Lovi Acabados.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>


   </div>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres lograr?, en tu ejemplo no cargas el javascript de materialize, por lo que no funcionaran algunos elementos del framework, especifica mejor tu pregunta, a que te refieres con galeria.

Comment: bueno bueno mira la galeria de materialize css funciona en si con rueditas abajo de las fotos okey? yo quiero agregarle dos botones que te permita simular esas rueditas del silder de materialize css

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo, es cuestión de que lo adaptes. Saludos [https://www.codeply.com/go/zAc3W2rzOd](https://www.codeply.com/go/zAc3W2rzOd)

Comment: En la documentación oficial lo puedes encontrar. [https://materializecss.com/pagination.html](https://materializecss.com/pagination.html) Saludos.